# How do I state why I am doing something?

Tags: reason

How can I say: "I am studying Japanese because I am going to Japan in October". The closest I have come is: "十月に日本に行きので日本語を勉強しています". But this sounds a little clumsy so I was wondering if there was a better (or different) way to express my reason than using ので and the nuances of this word (subtext; is it formal or casual, does it carry any implications?).

Comment: It should be 行**く**ので, not 行きので.

Comment: Or 行きます to sound a little more formal.

Answer (score 1):

The correct (or one of the correct) answers would be 「十月に日本に行くので日本語を勉強しています。」Just replace 「行き」with 「行く」。「行く」in this sense translates to "am going"/"will go". Replacing 「ので」with 「から」also works in an informal sense - 「ので」is more formal than 「から」。